# App xamarin mostrando uma hora adiantada

Tags: c#, xamarin

Aqui na empresa temos um aplicativo de bater ponto, nesse aplicativo é mostrado a hora atual na tela.

Ex: 
`viewModel.HoraAtual = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");`

Está mostrando sempre uma hora adianta em alguns celulares, alguém já passou por esse problema?

Comment: ele não está com a tabela Z (não lembro o resto) que define o Time Zome desatualizado? tipo, por causa do "Não horário de verão"

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema pode ser a definição de timezone errada nos dispositivos. Vi um problema parecido assim no passado ser resolvido com conversões de timezone. Consegue testar para ver se resolveria no seu caso?

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id));
```

Comment: vou testar, mas acredito que seja problema do horário de verão, quando coloco a região da Bahia que não tem horário de verão funciona, estou tentando também utilizar o BaseUtcOffset onde não é considerado o horário de verão, publiquei uma versão do App, se funcionar informo vocês